# Unexpected token in kafkajs code for a kafka consumer application

Tags: kafkajs

Nodejs version : 4.4.7
NPM version: 2.15.8

I am running the following code, which is literally copied from the following URL

https://kafka.js.org/docs/getting-started

```
    const { Kafka } = require('kafkajs')

    const kafka = new Kafka({
    clientId: 'my-app',
    brokers: ['kafka1:9092', 'kafka2:9092']
    })
```

The above code is saved in "apps.js" file under a "simpleapp" folder. In addition to that I  have installed the following

```
    npm install kafkajs
```

When I run the app.js file I get the following error

```
    /Users/nick/Documents/nodeprojects/simpleapp/apps.js:1
(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { const { Kafka } = require('kafkajs')
                                                                    ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token {
    at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:53:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:373:25)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:343:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:441:10)
    at startup (node.js:139:18)
    at node.js:968:3
```

What is the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Version 4.4.7 of NodeJS is very old, and isn't even supported anymore. [KafkaJS follows the same support schedule as NodeJS itself](https://github.com/tulios/kafkajs/issues/251), so the oldest currently supported version is 8.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Never expected brew to install a super old version of NodeJS. I will upgrade and run the same. Thanks